# C#-Running Hadoop_job-Getting error(C#)

Tags: c#, hadoop, mapreduce

I am getting following error when I run the `Mapreducer` job from my local computer.

```
Null Object Cannot be converted to a value type on the following line:
 var result = hadoop.MapReduceJob.ExecuteJob<UserQuestionsExtractionJob>();
```

Comment: Can you provide the full code @Mona?

Comment: Sure, here is the code , thank you.

Comment: can you please check the code from her, since it is too long to be here:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620717/Building-A-Recommendation-Engine-Machine-Learning

Comment: Did you fixed this error @Mona ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on a different hadoop project, I figured there was an exception somewhere in the mapper class, so just used    try    catch    in the mapper method and started to work.